# Understanding partial differential equation requirement

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I'm reading about separation of variables in my Fourier series book and there is one requirement in a problem I don't understand. Here it is:

[image]

I don't understand, why can't the $\sqrt{-A}$ take a real value? in (1.26)? Why does it need to be integer?...Why can't it be for example $1.05$? Why isn't it then well-defined?

Please let me know if you need more reference from my source :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\sqrt{-A}$ was not an integer, then $\Theta$ would not have period $2\pi$, i.e. $\Theta(2\pi) \ne \Theta(0)$.  But physically $\theta = 0$ and $\theta = 2\pi$ correspond to the same position on the rod, so the temperature must be
the same at $2\pi$ as at $0$.